# How can I achieve the dowm part of this page? I have tried grid and flex

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve the layout of this page from the "Limitation of BMI". I tried `grid`, but I couldn't achieve what I wanted, or maybe I wasn't able to manipulate it because the desktop, tablet, and mobile view are different.

See the:

[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1hUI.jpg)
[Tablet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tnUV.jpg)
[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP3eE.jpg)

I grouped different rows separately, each with `grid`. See the HTML tags below:

```css
.ftb {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 250px;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px 150px 20px 50px;
}

[class*="ftbk"] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 250px;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: end;
  margin: 10px;
}

[class*="item-"] {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px 0px rgb(231, 245, 254);
}

.ftbk2 {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.ftbk3 {
  padding-right: 200px;
}

.diff-1 {
  padding: px;
}

.icon_tittle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
}

.icon_tittle .material-symbols-outlined {
  padding: 0;
}


/* Icon Styles */

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 600, 'GRAD' 200, 'opsz' 48;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.soup_kitchen {
  background-color: #fcddec;
  color: #f273b3;
}

.exercise {
  background-color: #f9ede0;
  color: #eb8014;
}

.sleep {
  background-color: #d8f4f7;
  color: #88dcdd;
}

.gender {
  color: #f5b39a;
}

.age {
  color: #aee8e7;
}

.muscle {
  color: #c598f2;
}

.pregnancy {
  color: #fde998;
}

.race {
  color: #f699c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="ftb">
  <div class="diff-1">
    <h2>Limitations of BMI</h2>
    <p>Although BMI is often a practical indicator of healthy weight, it is not suited for every person. Specific groups should carefully consider their BMI outcomes, and in certain cases, the measurement may not be beneficial to use.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="icon_tittle">
      <div><span class="material-symbols-outlined gender">woman</span></div>
      <h4>Gender</h4>
    </div>
    <p>The development and body fat composition of girls and boys vary with age. Consequently, a child's age and gender are considered when evaluating their BMI.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ftbk2">
  <div class="item-3">
    <div class="icon_tittle">
      <div><span class="material-symbols-outlined age">cake</span></div>
      <h4>Age</h4>
    </div>
    <p>In aging individuals, increased body fat and muscle loss may cause BMI to underestimate body fat content.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-4">
    <div class="icon_tittle">
      <div><span class="material-symbols-outlined muscle">sports_gymnastics</span></div>
      <h4>Muscle</h4>
    </div>
    <p>BMI may misclassify muscular individuals as overweight or obese, as it doesn't differentiate muscle from fat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ftbk3">
  <div class="item-5">
    <div class="icon_tittle">
      <div><span class="material-symbols-outlined pregnancy">pregnancy</span></div>
      <h4>Pregnancy</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Expectant mothers experience weight gain due to their growing baby. Maintaining a healthy pre-pregnancy BMI is advisable to minimize health risks for both mother and child.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-6">
    <div class="icon_tittle">
      <div><span class="material-symbols-outlined race">directions_run</span></div>
      <h4>Race</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Certain health concerns may affect individuals of some Black and Asian origins at lower BMIs than others. To learn more, it is advised to discuss this with your GP or practice nurse.</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this : https://codepen.io/cecileledoux/pen/BaGKwMO

You will need to update width of columns for the last one.

```
section{
  display: grid;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "title" "text" "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5";
  grid-gap:20px;
}
section > *{
  background:#fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
section > h1{
  grid-area: title;
}
section > p{
  grid-area: text;
}
#a1{
  grid-area: a1;
}
#a2{
  grid-area: a2;
}
#a3{
  grid-area: a3;
}
#a4{
  grid-area: a4;
}
#a5{
  grid-area: a5;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  section{
    background:#aaf;
    grid-template-areas: "title title title title" "text text text text" "a1 a1 a2 a2" "a3 a3 a4 a4" ". a5 a5 .";
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
  section{
    background:#faf;
    grid-template-areas:
      "title title title . a1 a1 a1 ."
      "text text text . a1 a1 a1 ."
      ". . a2 a2 a2 a3 a3 a3"
      ". a4 a4 a5 a5 a5 . .";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 100px 40px 60px 40px 50px 
  }
}

<section>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate asperiores eveniet explicabo numquam, eius iusto consectetur eos soluta reprehenderit earum dolore velit amet accusantium praesentium aliquam rem similique quae odit.</p>
  <article id="a1">
    <h1>❄️ title 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis veritatis delectus accusamus soluta hic possimus, enim quae officia rem! Perspiciatis esse necessitatibus impedit hic consequatur facere omnis vero, mollitia tenetur.</p>
  </article>
  <article id="a2">
    <h1>❄️ title 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis veritatis delectus accusamus soluta hic possimus, enim quae officia rem! Perspiciatis esse necessitatibus impedit hic consequatur facere omnis vero, mollitia tenetur.</p>
  </article>
  <article id="a3">
    <h1>❄️ title 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis veritatis delectus accusamus soluta hic possimus, enim quae officia rem! Perspiciatis esse necessitatibus impedit hic consequatur facere omnis vero, mollitia tenetur.</p>
  </article>
  <article id="a4">
    <h1>❄️ title 4</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis veritatis delectus accusamus soluta hic possimus, enim quae officia rem! Perspiciatis esse necessitatibus impedit hic consequatur facere omnis vero, mollitia tenetur.</p>
  </article>
  <article id="a5">
    <h1>❄️ title 5</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis veritatis delectus accusamus soluta hic possimus, enim quae officia rem! Perspiciatis esse necessitatibus impedit hic consequatur facere omnis vero, mollitia tenetur.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: This explains the tablet and mobile view. but the desktop view is what I have issue with.

Comment: The desktop is included, it's the "min width 1000px" part